# Postres/Python - is it better to use one large query, or several smaller ones? How do you decide number of items to include in 'WHERE IN' clause?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, database-administration

I am writing a Python script that will be run regularly in a production environment where efficiency is key.

Below is an anonymized query that I have which pulls sales data for 3,000 different items.

I **think** I am getting slower results querying for all of them at once. When I try querying for different sizes, the amount of time it takes varies inconsistently (likely due to my internet connection). For example, sometimes querying for 1000 items 3 times is faster than all 3000 at once. However, running the same test 5 minutes later gets me different results. It is a production database where performance may be dependent on current traffic. I am not a database administrator but work in data science, using mostly similar select queries (I do the rest in Python).

**Is there a best practice here? Some sort of logic that determines how many items to put in the *WHERE IN* clause?**

```
date_min = pd.to_datetime('2021-11-01')
date_max = pd.to_datetime('2022-01-31')
sql = f"""
    SELECT
        product_code,
        sales_date,
        n_sold,
        revenue
    FROM
        sales_daily
    WHERE
        product_code IN {tuple(item_list)}
        and sales_date >= DATE('{date_min}')
        and sales_date <= DATE('{date_max}')
    ORDER BY
        sales_date DESC, revenue
    """
df_act = pd.read_sql(sql, di.db_engine)
df_act
```

Comment: The query is not hitting a minimal number of rows, so I would assume it's not an interactive one, but a batch one that you probably run off hours. It it takes less than 5 minutes I would consider it "fast"; otherwise there should be some optimization work.

Comment: The date ranges are not helping performance either.  Since you are doing postprocessing anyway, why not remove all the WHERE clauses and do the date and product_code filtering locally?

Comment: @WombatPM - would you still suggest this if there are over 500k product_codes with daily sales data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `sales_date` column is indexed in the database, I think using a function in the where clause (`DATE`) might cause the plan to not use that index. I believe you will have better luck if you concatenate `date_min` and `date_max` as strings (YYYY-MM-DD) into the SQL string and get rid of the function. Also, use `BETWEEN...AND` rather than `>= ... AND ... <=`.

As for `IN` with 1000 items, strongly recommend you don't do that. Create a single-column temp table of those values and index the item, then join to product_code.

Generally, something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _item_list;
CREATE TEMP TABLE _item_list
AS
SELECT item
FROM VALUES (etc) t(item);

CREATE INDEX idx_items ON _item_list (item);

    SELECT
        product_code,
        sales_date,
        n_sold,
        revenue
    FROM
        sales_daily x
        INNER JOIN _item_list y ON x.product_code = y.item
    WHERE
        sales_date BETWEEN '{date_min}' AND '{date_max}'
    ORDER BY
        sales_date DESC, revenue
```

As an addendum, try to have the items in the item list in the same order as the index on the product_code.